# Can I use a random generator without specifying a number distribution?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, cross-platform

I'm working on a mobile game, and I needed to create a possibility to play the same level in an absolutely same way. This sounded easy because I knew about a seed for a random generator, which should be the same for this purpose.

The problem arised later, when I used `std::mt19937` together with `std::uniform_int_distribution` as it was in many tutorials. As it was noticed in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903356/c11-random-number-distributions-are-not-consistent-across-platforms-what-al) , random number distributions aren't consistent between platforms, while the engine is consistent (how can it be differenent, if it is based on a mathematical algorithm?).

I didn't pay much attention at this problem and just used `std::mt19937` without a distribution.

Is it a correct way of usage, if there is no particular requirements on number distribution?

Comment: You can always code your own distribution, or an entire pseudo-random generator from scratch, that would be consistent across your platforms. For something as meaningless as a mobile game, I doubt that the mathematical qualities of pseudo-random number generation are very important.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks, I agree with you that one more mobile game with not big ranges of required numbers doesn't need high mathematical quality.

Comment: related/maybe dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38367976/4342498

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::mt19937`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) produces uniform random numbers in the range [0, 2<sup>32</sup>-1]. It implements the [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) alrogithm and is guaranteed to provide reproducible results across implementations.

If you need a different range, you need to somehow reduce [0, 2<sup>32</sup>-1] to your desired range. [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) is a convenience tool for doing that (but provides no guarantee of portability across implementations).

Comment: @rustyx; You have to be very rich.

Answer (score 4):

The random number *generator* `std::mt19937` will generate the same values for any platform, but alas the standard allows `std::uniform_int_distribution` to be flexible.

So you need to do the transformation yourself alas.

Comment: @UmNyobe: http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/ARTICLES/mt.pdf for the generator along with the standard for the specification of the implementation. For `std::uniform_int_distribution` see the standard again; the transformation function is not specified. https://en.cppreference.com/w/ is an adequate proxy for the standard, and it's free.

Comment: The paper mentioned by @Bathsheba specifies the state transitions. It does not specify the seeding used in the C++ Standard.